# CSS animation - animate one element after another

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I wanting to animate one element then another then another, is this possible with CSS? I can't seem to get it working, [here](http://jsbin.com/licapepose/1/edit?html,css,output) is my attempt so far.
I have two major problems:

1) My animation does not happen. 
 
2) When it does happen, it will animate each element at the same time, what I wanting is animate the next element when the last has finished. Does CSS have this kind of capability yet? 
 
3) I want it to be infinite.

I think I have name 3, but my animation wont play so I cannot test it. I am trying to make a loading animation, ideally I dont want to use JS as I assume this would be bad practice?

Comment: as far as i can tell there is no callback function in css that would enable you to find out when the animation is finished and thus start the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the jQuery tag on the question I'm providing a jQuery approach.  I think it is cleaner if you want infinite approach.  [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hwuvxL1q/2/)

I added display:none; to your e class:

```
.e {display:none;}
```

And use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to process the collection of elements supplied by the jQuery selector `$('.e')`.

```
(function($){
    (function fadeNext(collection){
        collection.eq(0).fadeIn(1000, function(){
            (collection=collection.slice(1)).length 
            && fadeNext(collection)
        });
    })($('.e'))
})(jQuery)
```

Edit in response to comment:

Be careful with infinite.  You probably want to add a clearTimout() call you stop execution after you deem it is no longer necessary.  Here is the updated js code ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwuvxL1q/4/)):

```
(function($){

    var el = $('.e');
    var animationLength = 1000;
    var duration = el.length * animationLength + animationLength;
    var clearAfter = 100;
    var animation;

    function fadeNext(collection){
        collection.eq(0).fadeIn(animationLength, function(){
            (collection=collection.slice(1)).length 
            && fadeNext(collection)
        });
    }

    function play(){
        fadeNext(el);
        animation = setTimeout(function(){
            el.hide();
            play();
        }, duration);
    }
    play();

    setTimeout(function(){
         clearTimeout(animation);   
    }, duration * clearAfter);
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: This looks really clean, and I think I am going to have to go with a jQuery solution to be honest. How would I go about making this loop infinitly?

Comment: Updated answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add different `animation-delay` to all elements.

Demo using `animation-direction: alternate` ---> [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/duqojuxera/2/edit)

```css
@keyframes load {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.e {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.one {
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite;
  animation: load 5s infinite;
}
.two {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 1s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 1s;
}
.three {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 2s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 2s;
}
.four {
  background: pink;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 3s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 3s;
}
.five {
  background: purple;
  -webkit-animation: load 5s infinite 4s;
  animation: load 5s infinite 4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="e one"></div>
<div class="e two"></div>
<div class="e three"></div>
<div class="e four"></div>
<div class="e five"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old ticket, but I hope my answer may help someone.

If you are okay to use css plugin then use this:
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Keep handy custom CSS for delay and use accordingly like this:

```
.anim-delay-500ms   { animation-delay: 0.5s }
.anim-delay-1000ms  { animation-delay: 1s }
.anim-delay-1500ms  { animation-delay: 1.5s }
.anim-delay-2000ms  { animation-delay: 2s }
```

HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="animated fadeInDown anim-delay-500ms">First Content</div>
<div class="animated fadeInDown anim-delay-1500ms">Second Content</div>
<div class="animated fadeInDown anim-delay-2000ms">Third Content</div>
<div class="animated fadeInDown anim-delay-2500ms">Fourth Content</div>
```

Here is few additional control to use with animation.css

```
#yourElement {
  -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
  -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
  -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

*Note: be sure to replace "vendor" in the CSS with the applicable vendor prefixes (webkit, moz, etc)*

For more documentation you can refer here:
https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. This solution is faster and prettier.

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec Technically this is just css3 animation. This can be done without a library that would have extra code loaded in just to animate a few things since the library has css for other animation as well. Doing what weafs.py said is the same thing. Just decrease duration time to speed it up.